# ASCII art generator in C

Tags: c, library, ascii-art, dynamic-loading

I have written an ASCII art generator library. I was practicing data abstraction and code abstraction and I wanted to know if there is something that can be improved.

File tree:

> ```
>    |         |--Makefile
>    |--fonts--|--StarStrips.c
>    |         |--whimsy.c
>    |
>    |           |--core.h 
> ---|--include--|--StarStrips.h
>    |           |--whimsy.h
>    |
>    |--Makefile
> ```

**/fonts/Makefile**

```c
sharedlib: whimsy.o StarStrips.o
    @echo Building the Shared Library;  \
    gcc  -shared -fPIC -o ascii-arts.so whimsy.o StarStrips.o;  
StarStrips.o : StarStrips.c
    @echo building StarStrips;          \
    gcc -c -fPIC StarStrips.c -o StarStrips.o -std=c99 -I../include 
whimsy.o : whimsy.c
    @echo building whimsy;          \
    gcc -c -fPIC whimsy.c -o whimsy.o -std=c99 -I../include
```

**/font/whimsy.c**

```c
#include <whimsy.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int whimsy_allowed(int c)
{
    return islower(c) || c == ' ';
}

int whimsy_index (int c)
{
    return  islower(c)? c -'a'+1 :0;
}

int whimsy_init(void){
    font_alloc(whimsy,10,27);
    d_alloc(whimsy,space,' ',5,ARRAY({
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    ",
            "    "          }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,a,'a',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            " d888b8b  ",
            "d8P' ?88  ",
            "88b  ,88b ",
            "`?88P'`88b",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,b,'b',11,ARRAY({
            " d8b      ",
            " ?88      ",
            "  88b     ",
            "  888888b ",
            "  88P `?8b",
            " d88,  d88",
            "d88'`?88P'",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,c,'c',8,ARRAY({
            "       ",
            "       ",
            "       ",
            " d8888b",
            "d8P' `P",
            "88b    ",
            "`?888P'",
            "       ",
            "       ",
            "       "       }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,d,'d',11,ARRAY({
            "      d8b ",
            "      88P ",
            "     d88  ",
            " d888888  ",
            "d8P' ?88  ",
            "88b  ,88b ",
            "`?88P'`88b",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,e,'e',8,ARRAY({
            "       ",
            "       ",
            "       ",
            " d8888b",
            "d8b_,dP",
            "88b    ",
            "`?888P'",
            "       ",
            "       ",
            "       "       }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,f,'f',11,ARRAY({
            "   ,d8888b",
            "   88P'   ",
            "d888888P  ",
            "  ?88'    ",
            "  88P     ",
            " d88      ",
            "d88'      ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,g,'g',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            " d888b8b  ",
            "d8P' ?88  ",
            "88b  ,88b ",
            "`?88P'`88b",
            "       )88",
            "      ,88P",
            "  `?8888P "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,h,'h',11,ARRAY({
            " d8b      ",
            " ?88      ",
            "  88b     ",
            "  888888b ",
            "  88P `?8b",
            " d88   88P",
            "d88'   88b",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,i,'i',6,ARRAY({
            "  d8,",
            " `8P ",
            "     ",
            "  88b",
            "  88P",
            " d88 ",
            "d88' ",
            "     ",
            "     ",
            "     "         }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,j,'j',8,ARRAY({
            "   d8, ",
            "  `8P  ",
            "       ",
            "  d88  ",
            "  ?88  ",
            "   88b ",
            "   `88b",
            "    )88",
            "   ,88P",
            "`?888P "       }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,k,'k',12,ARRAY({
            " d8b       ",
            " ?88       ",
            "  88b      ",
            "  888  d88'",
            "  888bd8P' ",
            " d88888b   ",
            "d88' `?88b,",
            "           ",
            "           ",
            "           "       }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,l,'l',6,ARRAY({
            " d8b ",
            " 88P ",
            "d88  ",
            "888  ",
            "?88  ",
            " 88b ",
            "  88b",
            "     ",
            "     ",
            "     "         }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,m,'m',15,ARRAY({
            "              ",
            "              ",
            "              ",
            "  88bd8b,d88b ",
            "  88P'`?8P'?8b",
            " d88  d88  88P",
            "d88' d88'  88b",
            "              ",
            "              ",
            "              "    }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,n,'n',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "  88bd88b ",
            "  88P' ?8b",
            " d88   88P",
            "d88'   88b",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,o,'o',9,ARRAY({
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            " d8888b ",
            "d8P' ?88",
            "88b  d88",
            "`?8888P'",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        "      }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,p,'p',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "?88,.d88b,",
            "`?88'  ?88",
            "  88b  d8P",
            "  888888P'",
            "  88P'    ",
            " d88      ",
            " ?8P      "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,q,'q',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            ".d88b,.88P",
            "88P  `88P'",
            "?8b  d88  ",
            "`?888888  ",
            "    `?88  ",
            "      88b ",
            "      ?8P "        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,r,'r',10,ARRAY({
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "  88bd88b",
            "  88P'  `",
            " d88     ",
            "d88'     ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         "     }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,s,'s',9,ARRAY({
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            " .d888b,",
            " ?8b,   ",
            "   `?8b ",
            "`?888P' ",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        "      }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,t,'t',9,ARRAY({
            "        ",
            "   d8P  ",
            "d888888P",
            "  ?88'  ",
            "  88P   ",
            "  88b   ",
            "  `?8b  ",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        "      }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,u,'u',10,ARRAY({
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "?88   d8P",
            "d88   88 ",
            "?8(  d88 ",
            "`?88P'?8b",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         "     }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,v,'v',10,ARRAY({
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "?88   d8P",
            "d88  d8P'",
            "?8b ,88' ",
            "`?888P'  ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         "     }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,w,'w',16,ARRAY({
            "               ",
            "               ",
            "               ",
            " ?88   d8P  d8P",
            " d88  d8P' d8P'",
            " ?8b ,88b ,88' ",
            " `?888P'888P'  ",
            "               ",
            "               ",
            "               "   }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,x,'x',10,ARRAY({
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "?88,  88P",
            " `?8bd8P'",
            " d8P?8b, ",
            "d8P' `?8b",
            "         ",
            "         ",
            "         "
                        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,y,'y',11,ARRAY({
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "          ",
            "?88   d8P ",
            "d88   88  ",
            "?8(  d88  ",
            "`?88P'?8b ",
            "       )88",
            "      ,d8P",
            "   `?888P'"        }));
    d_alloc(whimsy,z,'z',9,ARRAY({
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "d88888P ",
            "   d8P' ",
            " d8P'   ",
            "d88888P'",
            "        ",
            "        ",
            "        "      }));
    return 0;
}
int whimsy_exit(void){
    for(int i=0;i<whimsy.d_n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<whimsy.c;j++)
            free(whimsy.d[i][j]);
    for(int i=0;i<whimsy.d_n;i++)
        free(whimsy.d[i]);
    free(whimsy.d);
    free(whimsy.r);
}
int whimsy_print(const char* s){
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                if(whimsy.allowed(s[i]) != 1)
                        return -1;
    for (int i=0;i<whimsy.c;i++)
        {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                        fputs(whimsy.d[whimsy.index(s[j])][i],stdout);
                putchar('\n');
        }

}
```

I won't show you **/font/StarStrips.c** because it's similar lengthy code and the goal of reviewing the code is not giving opinions about the fonts self.

**/include/core.h**

```c
#ifndef _ascii_arts_core_
#define _ascii_arts_core_
/*
r rows
c columns
d design
char_n number of characters
*/
struct font{
unsigned int c;
unsigned int *r;
unsigned int d_n;
int (*allowed)(int);
int (*index)(int);
int (*init)(void);
int (*exit)(void);
int (*print)(const char*);
char ***d;
};
#define XX(a,b,c) a##b##c
#define font_alloc(font,column,nofdesigns)              \
    do{                             \
        font.d_n = nofdesigns;                  \
        font.c = column;                    \
        font.r = malloc(sizeof(int)*font.d_n);          \
            font.d = malloc(sizeof(char***)*font.d_n);      \
        for(int i=0;i<font.d_n;i++)             \
            font.d[i] =malloc(sizeof(char**)*font.c);   \
    }while(0)
#define ARRAY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define d_alloc(font,__tok,_char,row,design)                \
    do{                             \
        font.r[font.index(_char)] = row;            \
        for(int j=0;j<font.c;j++)               \
            font.d[font.index(_char)][j] =          \
            malloc(sizeof(char*)*font.r[font.index(_char)]);\
        char * temp[]  = design;                \
        for(int i=0;i<font.c;i++)               \
            strcpy(font.d[font.index(_char)][i],temp[i]);   \
    }while(0)
#endif
```

**/include/whimsy.h**

```c
#ifndef _whimsy_font_
#define _whimsy_font_
#include <core.h>
int whimsy_allowed(int c);
int whimsy_index(int c);
int whimsy_init(void);
int whimsy_exit(void);
int whimsy_print(const char* s);
struct font whimsy = {
    .allowed = whimsy_allowed,
    .index = whimsy_index,
    .init = whimsy_init,
    .exit = whimsy_exit,
    .print = whimsy_print
};
#endif
```

**/Makefile**

```c
uninstall:
    @echo Uninstalling library;     \
    rm /usr/lib/libaarts.so -f;     \
    cd /usr/include         \
    rm whimsy.h core.h StarStrips.h -f
install: lib
    @echo Installing library;   \
    cp include/*.h /usr/include/;   \
    cp libaarts.so /usr/lib/
lib:
    @cd fonts;          \
    make sharedlib;         \
    mv ascii-arts.so ../libaarts.so

clean:
    @rm *.so -f;            \
    cd fonts;           \
    rm *.o -f;          \
    cd ../demo;         \
    rm *.d -f;
demos:
    @cd demo;           \
    make whimsy
```

**Little notes**

First of all, the main goal of this library was to provide a data structure to hold fonts for ASCII art characters and maybe ASCII art drawings (i.e. converting a PNG image to ASCII arts (not yet done)).

in the `d_alloc` macro the `__tok` parameter is useless and it is there just for backwards comptiability with previous versions of the same library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **fonts/Makefile**

  Each object depends only on the corresponding source. It means that header modifications wouldn't trigger recompilation. You may fix it by explicitly spelling out dependencies:

  ```
  whimsy.o: whimsy.c whimsy.h core.h
  ```

  In general it is a good habit to have dependencies auto generated: even in your not very complicated case it is easy to miss the `core.h` dependency. Take a look at `-M` family of `gcc` options.
- **include/whimsy.h**

  Do not *define* objects (like `struct font whimsy`) in the header file. You never know how many times the client would happen to `#include "whimsy.h"` in different places of their project. Better practice is to have the *definition* in the `.c` file, and *declare* it in the header as

  ```
  extern struct font whimsy;
  ```
- **DRY?**

  Unfortunately, you didn't show your font file. Also, I'm 95% sure the `init` and `print` files are identical modulo font name. If I'm correct, you need to unify them, and have the unified version in `core.c`.
- **Allocation**

  Allocating glyphs dynamically and copying them from a static area looks like a waste for me (it would make sense should you read glyphs from the text file instead). I would have a

  ```
  struct glyph {
      int width;
      char * appearance;
  };
  ```

  (strictly speaking, `glyph.width` is redundant: given a font height and appearance length you may calculate width at runtime); an array of glyphs as a part of `struct font`:

  ```
  struct font {
      ....
      struct glyph typeface[128];
      ....
  }
  ```

  and a static initialization of each font like

  ```
  static struct font whimsy = {
      ....
      .typeface = {
          ....
          ['a'] = (struct glyph) {
              .width = 10,
              .appearance =
                  "          "
                  "          "
                  "          "
                  " d888b8b  "
                  "d8P' ?88  "
                  "88b  ,88b "
                  "`?88P'`88b"
                  "          "
                  "          "
                  "          ";
          },
          ....    
      },
      ....
  };
  ```

  Beware that such partial array initialization is a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).
- **More abstraction**

  Now you may take advantage of `appearance` being default initialized to an `NULL`, and conclude that such glyph is not implemented. An `allowed` method becomes a trivial test, and is easily abstracted out of the font specifics.

Comment: so where can I look for `-M` option I googled it but I couldn't find any clue

Comment: Start with http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104807/a-basic-modern-idiomatic-gnu-makefile/104838#104838. For full docs, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options. Search keywords are "makefile automatic dependency generation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to format you code properly. Things like these are hard to read:

   > ```
   > struct font{
   > unsigned int c;
   > unsigned int *r;
   > unsigned int d_n;
   > int (*allowed)(int);
   > int (*index)(int);
   > int (*init)(void);
   > int (*exit)(void);
   > int (*print)(const char*);
   > char ***d;
   > };
   > ```

   Hard to read code is more difficult to maintain and you're more likely to miss a bug.
2. Use braces consistently. Things like these just lead to trouble in the long run and don't make the code any easier to read.

   > ```
   > for(int i=0;i<whimsy.d_n;i++)
   >     for(int j=0;j<whimsy.c;j++)
   >         free(whimsy.d[i][j]);
   > ```

   Adding additional braces and formatting makes it very explicit what the scope of each loop is and adding additional statements you're less likely to accidentally forget to add a brace.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < whimsy.d_n; i++) {
       for(int j = 0; j < whimsy.c; j++) {
           free(whimsy.d[i][j]);
       }
    }
   ```
3. The use of defines for `font_alloc` and `d_malloc` are a pretty bad abuse of the pre-processor. You just use it as an automated copy-n-paste mechanism and copy-n-paste code is bad. `#define` has it's uses but in this case it's the wrong choice.

Answer (score 3):

Portability: `islower()` is great, but `c -'a'+1` assumes consecutive `a-z`.  So if you want to work with those *rare* non-ASCII machines ...

```
int whimsy_index (int c) {
  if (islower(c)) {
    char s[2] = { c, '\0' };
    // Use base 36
    return strtol(s, 0, 36) - 10 + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Complex macros: Unclear as to the value of `#define font_alloc()`.  Instead make a function.

Clear pointers.  `whimsy_exit()` should not assume what the calling code does afterward with `whimsy` and its fields.  Since this code frees the allocation, then `NULL` the pointers and zero the count.

```
int whimsy_exit(void){
  ....
  for(int i=0;i<whimsy.d_n;i++) {
     free(whimsy.d[i]);
  }
```

Use `size_t` for array index.  `int` may not be wide enough.

```
int whimsy_print(const char* s){
  // int n = strlen(s);
  size_t n = strlen(s);
  // for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(size_t i= 0; i < n; i++)
```

Avoid magic numbers.  Why 10?  Why 27?  Even better, compute  10, 27 from the code.

```
int whimsy_init(void){
  // font_alloc(whimsy,10,27);
  #define WIDTH 10
  #define DESIGN_COUNT 27
  font_alloc(whimsy, WIDTH, DESIGN_COUNT);
```

Comment: +1 for the compatibility with rare non-Ascii machines I wish I could upvote you twice :)

Comment: @oddcoder My version of that is the `size_t` idea (though there are instances where it's caused problems having unsigned it can be done differently and it's safer in any case). Even though you couldn't up-vote the answer twice at least I can add to it - and have done. Portability tends to be a good thing too so together we have up-voted twice! :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Figlet](http://www.figlet.org/), which is very much the same thing you're doing.

As others have mentioned, I think it would be a good idea to separate font resources from code. Currently fonts are just C source files compiled into the application binary. A better way would be to define fonts in a plain text format making font creation easier and accessible to non-programmers as well.

Take a look at the [FIGFont Standard](http://www.jave.de/figlet/figfont.html), which specifies the font file format used by Figlet. If you were to implement this, you would have [lots of fonts](http://www.figlet.org/fontdb.cgi) all ready to go.

I realize the Figlet fonts are a bit more complicated than what you currently do, and if you think it's too much you could settle for a simplified version without smushing and kerning.

Below is a sample from [basic.flf](http://www.figlet.org/fonts/basic.flf) by Craig O'Flaherty.

```
 .d8b. $@
d8' `8b$@
88ooo88$@
88~~~88$@
88   88$@
YP   YP$@
       $@
       $@@
d8888b.$@
88  `8D$@
88oooY'$@
88~~~b.$@
88   8D$@
Y8888P'$@
       $@
       $@@
 .o88b.$@
d8P  Y8$@
8P     $@
8b     $@
Y8b  d8$@
 `Y88P'$@
       $@
       $@@
```

Rendering "ABC" with Figlet using this font looks like this:

```
 .d8b.  d8888b.  .o88b. 
d8' `8b 88  `8D d8P  Y8 
88ooo88 88oooY' 8P      
88~~~88 88~~~b. 8b      
88   88 88   8D Y8b  d8 
YP   YP Y8888P'  `Y88P'
```